# AppleWatch - How to detect the index of page based interface?

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch, pagecontrol

Is there any way to detect that index of page am I?

I need this because I added a button in each page for to send info. to Iphone with a specific ID. (interaction between watch & iphone work)

[image: Page Based]